# Groovy method to add new Object to List is not working properly

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I have a Groovy code to manipulate an Array of JSON objects.

My input is like the following (name: accounts):

> [
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID": "00206847"
> },
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID": "00206855"
> },
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID": "00206852"
> }
> ]

And I need to manipulate it to add to each internal JSON a sequence number. The expected output is:

> [
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID ": "00206847",
> "Sequence ": "1"
> },
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID": "00206855",
> "Sequence ": "2"
> },
> {
> "F57UI02A_AID ": "00206852",
> "Sequence ": "3"
> }
> ]

In my code, I'm collecting all F57UI02A elements to get the number's list. Then, I iterate over each JSON element, in order to create a new single one, having both F57UI02A element and the sequence number that I want to assign.

```
def accountList = accounts.collect{ it.get("F57UI02A_AID") };
    
   int size = accounts.size();
   def currentElement = new JsonBuilder();
   String sequence = "";
   def outputArray = [];
    
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       sequence = i+1;
       currentElement F57UI02A_AID: accountList[i], Sequence: sequence;
       outputArray[i] = currentElement;
       //outputArray << currentElement;
   }
   
   returnMap.put("output", outputArray);
   return returnMap;
```

When I run a test, I obtain the following output, instead the expected one:

> [{"F57UI02A_AID":"00206852","Sequence":"3"}, {"F57UI02A_AID":"00206852","Sequence":"3"}, {"F57UI02A_AID":"00206852","Sequence":"3"}]

Do you know why I'm getting three instances of the last JSON element, instead of having the correct number/sequence in the output?

Comment: There’s only one current element and you keep updating it. Tangentially—there are Groovy-er ways to write this, likely worth exploring.

Comment: Not sure why. I'm inserting the 'currentElement' JSON into different Array positions. So I don't know why, at the end of the for-each, I have in all positions the same JSON that corresponds to the last iteration.

Comment: There is a single `JsonBuilder`. You create it, set some values on it, insert it into the array *(oddly not mapping or pushing, separate issue)*. The next iteration you set values on the **same** `JsonBuilder` and insert it into the array again. You’re building the array with multiple references to a single object.

Comment: You are totally right, I was using the same instance of the object on my update and insert. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you fixed your issue, but here is an idea on how to do this leveraging more features of Groovy:

```
import groovy.json.*

String input = """[ 
   { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206847" }, 
   { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206855" }, 
   { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206852" } ]
"""
List<Map> json = new JsonSlurper().with { it.parseText( input ) }
List<Map> output = json
   .findAll { it["F57UI02A_AID"] }
   .withIndex()
   .collect { 
      def (Map current, int seq) = it
      current.Sequence = seq + 1
      current
   }
println( JsonOutput.toJson( output ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add to the previous answer as there are a few more groovy things we can employ:

```
import groovy.json.*

String input = '''[ { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206847" }, 
                    { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206855" }, 
                    { "F57UI02A_AID": "00206852" } ]'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( input ) 
def output = json.findAll { it["F57UI02A_AID"] }
                 .indexed(1)
                 .collect { i, m -> m + [Sequence: i] }
println( JsonOutput.toJson( output ) )
```

produces the same output as the code in the accepted answer.